# CHMOD folder permissions to access by http

Tags: permissions, apache2, chmod

I have this ubuntu web server and I want to give permissions to access only by http but I don't want the folder to be visible to the network users. 
I have a subfolder were users upload some files and I want to hide that too.
Can I do it with CHMOD? How?

Answer (score 10):

By default, Apache on Ubuntu runs as www-data.

Let's assume your folder is located in /var/www/mysite.

You can do this:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mysite
chmod -R og-r /var/www/mysite
```

After doing this, www-data (the Web server) will have full access to the site's files, while other non-root users will have no access at all.

If you wish to allow select users to access the site, you can make the folder group-readable and add those users to the group www-data.

Comment: I try chmod 711 to mysite and worked.

Comment: I'v try @Carster solution and when I access my http page I get a blank page

Comment: Strange. Are you running Apache as web server? The specific commands I wrote will only work if your web server is running as www-data.

Answer (score 2):

Probably what will work is running your webserver under a dedicated user, have that user be the owner of the folder, and then chmod 700 the folder.

Answer (score 1):

chmod 711 Worked for me.
I found this useful tool that help me a loot understanding CHMOD
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/chmodcal.shtml